# C# out of scope dealing with mutliple sql statements

Tags: c#, sql

I have this code snippet:

The variable m is a string set as the Name returned by the first sql command, that is closed and then the second is used to return other details. At this point m is used to populate the view, but visual studio says it is an unassigned variable. How do I fix this?

```
SqlCommand mcom = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Rica].[dbo].[MaritialStatus] WHERE ID=" + myReader["MaritalStatusID"], mnner);

SqlDataReader mread = null;
mread = mcom.ExecuteReader();

while (mread.Read())
{
    m = mread["Name"].ToString();
}
mnner.Close();

user_table.Text = user_table.Text + "<tr><td>"+ myReader["PostCode"] +"</td>";

//user details
SqlConnection inner = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RicaConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
inner.Open();

SqlCommand icom = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Rica].[dbo].[User] WHERE ID=" + myReader["ID"], inner);

SqlDataReader iread = null;
iread = icom.ExecuteReader();

while (iread.Read())
{
    user_table.Text = user_table.Text + "<td>" + iread["NamePrefix"] + " " + iread["FirstName"] + " " + iread["LastName"] + "</td><td>" + iread["Username"] + "</td><td>" + g + "</td><td>" + m + "</td></tr>";
}

iread.Close();
```

Comment: use `using-statement` for your connections and commands.

Comment: @Tim I'd be more worried about the obvious sql injection and xss injection bugs ;p (to tracer tong: these are BIG problems)

Comment: did I forget to mention that I've changed my legal name to `Marc <script>alert('pwned')</script>` ?

Comment: fixed this myself by moving the variable initalition to the class body and using some extra validation. Also in this case sql injection is pretty much a non problem here as all injected data is coming from data drawn from the db anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is entirely correct that `m` is unassigned. For example, there could be **no rows returned**. Just set an initial value that you want to use for the no-rows case, for example:

```
string m = null;
```

More specifically, for an assignment in a `while` / `foreach` etc, the "definite assignment" after the `while` / `foreach` is the same as the "definite assignment" *before*, because it is possible that no iterations were performed (i.e. a `foreach` over an empty set, or `while` where the test returns `false` immediately).

I must also observe that there are **lots** of problems in your current code; lots of missing `using`, SQL injection vulnerabilities (these are potentially big problems), etc, xss vulnerabilities (this is also a huge problem).

Using a tool like dapper-dot-net would fix the SQL injection, allowing really easy parameterization and reading, with it handling correct disposal of the command / reader. The xss issue should be addressed by html-encoding correctly. Although in truth, it is rare to have SQL code and HTML code right next to each-other like this.

Answer (score 2):

Local variables are *initially* unassigned so you need to assign/initialize *them* before you use.

```
string m=string.Empty;
```

Comment: Worth noting that this is only a problem because the code written might not enter the while loop (if no data is returned from the query).  If there was another guaranteed assignment to `m` then the error wouldn't occur.